# adding .so files in android studio 1.0 , gradle 1.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, shared-libraries

I have check most of the solutions and hacks how to add SO files but most of them are work around in the old version of gradle ( .8 lower ). I've gone to each link and another, but still i end up hanging & failed. I also notice that most of them are old. Did gradle able to fix this issue?

Anyone who have the latest step how to add .SO files in android studio 1.0 with gradle 1.1?

thank you very much.

Steps i have tried in the new version :

```
1.) Create a jniLibs in app>src>main>jniLibs
2.) inside the folder i added 2 folders which is "armeabi" & "armeabi-v7a"
3.) inside those folder i added the so files
4.) build & compile (no changes in gradle setting)
```

** - Still having same error :  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found.**

** - No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/test.video.com.civi.video2-1/**